# Can Correlation and Spearman's Rank be compared?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, spearman-rho

[Pearson's Correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) is a measure of linear relationship between two variables

[Spearman's Rank correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) assesses how well the relationship between two variables can be described using a monotonic function.

Can these two quantities be compared in some way? Both correlation and Spearman's rank provide p-values under null hypothesis of the variables being independent. If the p-value of Spearman's rank is significantly smaller than that of correlation, can it be concluded that the underlying relationship between the two variables is better described by a monotonic function than a linear function? If yes, can this comparison be formalized, yielding a measure of purely-nonlinear monotonic relationship?